# I'm getting an error that a folder does not exist when creating a document with a file attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Alright, so I have three models which are `User` `Document` and `Folder`.
I'm using the gems Paperclip and Acts_as_tree. The point in this is that each user will be able to create a new document with an attached file. The user will also be able to create folders and in that folder, there will be documents.

The issue that I'm getting is that when I try to create a new document I get back the error "Folder must exist". This even happens when I'm in a folder and I'm creating a new document. I know I'm missing something small in my code but I can't seem to get it. I'll show my code.

Documents controller

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

 def new
  folder = current_user.folders.find_by_id(params[:folder_id]) if params[:folder_id]
  @document = current_user.documents.build({ folder: folder })
 end

 def create
  @document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
  if @document.save
   if @document.folder
    redirect_to @document.folder
   else
    redirect_to folders_path
   end
  else
   render :new
 end

private
 def
  @folder = current_user.folders.find_by_id(params[:document][:folder_id]) if params[:document]
  params.require(:document).permit(:upload_file, :folder_id, :user_id).merge(folder: @folder)
 end
end
```

Document model

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :folder

 has_attached_file :upload_file
 validates_attachment_content_type :upload_file, content_type: /.*/


end
```

Documents form

```
<%= form_for @document, html: {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
 <% @document.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg %></p>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.file_field :upload_file %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :folder_id %>
<% end %>
```

Folder model

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
 acts_as_tree
end
```

Comment: @sawa Why am I getting the error "Folder must exist" when creating a new document when I'm not uploading to any folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `belongs_to :folder` its mean that before saving the document object you must have `folder_id`

```
belongs_to :folder, #required: true
```

in rails 5 `belongs_to something` implies that `validates_presence_of :something_id`

so here either you should pass `folder_id` with your form inside hidden field
or if you don't need `folder_id` at the time of document creation then set it in model `optional: true`

```
belongs_to :folder, optional: true
```